# Скрытие/появление кнопки при пустом/заполненом поле ввода

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется код, который выполняет следующее: если поле ввода пустое, то кнопка отправки скрыта, если же в поле вводятся символы - кнопка появляется.

Но если в поле вставить (Ctrl+V) символы, то кнопка не появляется. Как решить эту проблему?

http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/

```
    $("input").keyup(function () {
       if ($(this).val()) {
          $("button").show();
       }
       else {
          $("button").hide();
       }
    });
    $("button").click(function () {
       $("input").val('');
       $(this).hide();
    });
```

Comment: на каком браузере не появляется?

Comment: @Grundy на Chrome

Comment: Странно, в последнем хроме срабатывает, но не работает если из контекстного меню выбирать _вставить_

Answer (score 3):

Вместо события `keyup` слушайте событие [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input). В исходном коде поменял только первую строчку:

```js
$("input").on("input", function() {
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $("button").show();
  } else {
    $("button").hide();
  }
});
$("button").click(function() {
  $("input").val('');
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<button>Clear</button>
```

**Upd.** В Chrome этот пример тут, в StackOverflow sandbox, не работает, похоже, [из-за бага jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245134/run-code-snippet-gives-uncaught-securityerror), создающего зачем-то лишний iframe:
[image: консоль с ошибками]

Вроде бы этот [баг был пофиксен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240486/snippets-editor-wont-insert-and-close-on-so/240709#240709) в StackOverflow, но, возможно, обновление не коснулось ru.stackoverflow @nicolas-chabanovsky ? [Сообщил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2450/7161) о баге.

Comment: в chrome (48.0.2564.97) не работает

Comment: Обновил ответ – ошибка в Chrome связана с безопасностью и плеером кода StackOverflow. В нормальном сайте должно работать.

Comment: Кстати, обращение к участнику из текста вопроса не сработает.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно слушать событие `change` вместо `keyup` на инпуте:

```
$("input").on('change', function () {
   if ($(this).val()) {
      $("button").show();
   }
   else {
      $("button").hide();
   }
});

$("button").click(function () {
   $("input").val('');
   $(this).hide();
});
```

Другим хитрым способом может быть использование css-селекторов [:valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) и [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) вместе с аттрибутом [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:required). В таком случае, у непустого инпута будет срабатывать селектор :valid, на присутствие которого можно добавлять стиль видимости кнопке рядом. Примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/SVxbW/173/

Comment: событие `change` - срабатывает перед `blur` а не по мере изменения значения, например, с помощью нажатия клавиш. Кроме того в jsfiddle - кнопка не показывается, так как ошибка в css

Comment: Поправил пример

Comment: без разницы как навешивать обработчик события `change`, оно в любом случае происходит перед событием `blur`, а не по нажатию клавишь. А да, вижу, что пример в ответе не поменялся.

Comment: Я поменял ссылку на пример, так что смотрите внимательнее :) Насчет change - предложите решение лучше, если считаете, что это не подходит. Я помню довольно сложный скрипт, который покрывает все возможные случаи, но не уверен, что он действительно требуется автору.

Comment: уже @Sergiks предложил :)

Comment: пример с :valid и :invalid интересен, но в моём случае я не могу использовать аттрибут required

Comment: @andre3000 а атрибут pattern?

Comment: @Grundy pattern можно и это было бы отличное решение, но к сожалению оно не поддерживается некоторыми браузерами

Answer (score 0):

Вариант ответа [@Sergiks](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488282/186999) без навешивания обработчика события *input* с помощью jQuery.

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (this.value) {
    document.getElementById('b').classList.add('show');
  } else {
    document.getElementById('b').classList.remove('show');
  }
});

$("button").click(function() {
  $("input").val('');
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
button {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<input />
<button id='b'>Clear</button>
```